# Row with duplicate values in one column and different values in a second column

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

In Power BI, I need to identify all distinct duplicate values in a `Column A` that have distinct values in `Column B`.

Example input:

```
Name    Index
-------------
john    1
mary    1
john    1
jim     1
john    2
mary    1
jim     2
jim     1
john    2
mary    2
```

Desired result:

```
Name    Index
-------------
john    1
mary    1
jim     1
john    2
jim     2
mary    2
```

Column Name in my Power BI is a concatenated column

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this pretty easily in the Power Query Editor GUI.

Select the combination of columns that you want to remove duplicates on (`name` and `index` in your case) and then under the Home tab you can select Remove Rows > Remove Duplicates.

[image: Query Editor GUI]

This will automatically generate the `Table.Distinct` M code that chillin suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Provided your previous step is a table, you should just be able to use:

```
Table.Distinct(nameOfPreviousStep, {"Name", "Index"})
```

Below is an example of what I mean:

```
let
    someTable = Table.FromRows({{"john",1},{"mary",1},{"john",1},{"jim",1},{"john",2},{"mary",1},{"jim",2},{"jim",1},{"john",2},{"mary",2}}, type table[Name=text, Index=Int64.Type]),
    removeDuplicates = Table.Distinct(someTable, {"Name", "Index"})
in
    removeDuplicates
```

Try it out and see if it gives you your expected output (I think it does based on what I've seen).